# How can I create non database page item in oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created page item in a form in oracle apex to display the name

How can I set the page item non database item

Now when click SAVE button it shows the following error :

```
Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P42_PATIENT_NAME. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an item that is for display only, then "Display Only" is the correct item type. Set the property "Send On Page Submit" to false to avoid the session state errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this error because I set the item type

```
Display only or read only
```

for this reason it show this error
and to create non database item just create the item and keep it text field or number field and it will not affect your form when you save